# How to save text from several UITextViews with one single Button in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, textview

[image: We have the following stuff]

We have 4 outlets (UITextView) and finally a save Button.

I want to be able to save whatever we write in all of each TextViews with one simple Button. How to do that? I've made this work but saving one UITextView.

The code:

```
class agendaDeSuen_os: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {      

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!     
    @IBOutlet weak var primerTextView: UITextView!        
    @IBOutlet weak var segundoTextView: UITextView!        
    @IBOutlet weak var tercerTextView: UITextView!        
    @IBOutlet weak var cuartoTextView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //ScrollViewSize
        scrollView.contentSize.height = 1400

        //Hide keyboard with touching anywhere
        var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "DismissKeyboard")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


        //Button
        let stringKey = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        segundoTextView.text = stringKey.stringForKey("savedStringKey")

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        return true
    }


    //Hide keyboard with return button
    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if text == "\n"
        {
            primerTextView.resignFirstResponder()
            segundoTextView.resignFirstResponder()
            tercerTextView.resignFirstResponder()
            cuartoTextView.resignFirstResponder()

            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    @IBAction func botonGuardar(sender: AnyObject) {

        let myText = segundoTextView.text


        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myText, forKey: "savedStringKey")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Guardado", message:"Tu texto se ha guardado", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)




    }








    //Hide keyboard with touching anywhere

    func DismissKeyboard(){


        view.endEditing(true)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you're talking about saving all the text to NSUserDefaults.
Simply do what you've done but with different keys for each one.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myText, forKey: "textView1")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(differentText, forKey: "textView2")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

And then you just use the different keys to access different saved objects (in your case Strings).

Does this make sense?

Loic

Answer (score 1):

could you not just add three more NSUserDefualts in the botonGuardar function, eg.

```
let myPrimerText = PrimerTextView.text

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myPrimerText, forKey: "savedPrimerStringKey")
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie for your time. First solution was great too.

Answer (score 1):

> take outlets into an array. Use fast enumeration

```
let array:[UITextViews] = @[textview1,textview2,textview3,textview4];


func saveTextViewData() {

for textView in array {

saved.append(textView.text)

   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Ramkumar . I have been able to fix it with your help =)